# Show text in a page as popup

Tags: 7

I have some text in my page. and a read more link. When i click on the link, it should open the text in a pop up window. Is there any module to do this? i need to just open the text in pop up not some URL /Html Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) for this; it's not a Drupal module but it's simple to create. Look at "Inline HTML" in the examples.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Popup module](http://drupal.org/project/popup), which may be useful.

Comment: It is only for D6

Comment: There is a [7.x-1.x-dev version](http://drupal.org/node/1118304)...

Answer (score 0):

[Shadowbox](http://drupal.org/project/shadowbox) is another candidate for Drupal 7.